Possible to show a struct/class' body in pop window or buffer
While using lsp-mode in Emacs, I can hover my mouse cursor over a struct type definition (like OpBuilder in this example) and a popup appears. This popup displays a description and declaration of the struct, but not the actual body of the struct definition.
